# Inner join after using aggregate function

Tags: r

I have such type of data (with like 10M rows and 20 columns) and I used aggregate function to

```
customer_id<-c("aks123","epfk123","jfk1234","ekdm453","ddd4356","epfk123","ffg234","aks123","jfk1234","ekdm453")
payment<-c("109","123","342","123","453","423","1009","198","124","138")
df<-data.frame(customer_id,payment)
```

Now I needed to group it by customer id and then keep them unique by average payment values

so I used this:

```
new1<-aggregate(df[,12], list(df$customer_id), mean)
```

this has about 5M rows

to merge this with the other data, I used `inner_join`:

```
inner_join(new1,df,by=c("customer_id"="customer_id"))
```

and now I am getting about 12 M rows of data. I don't understand if they are extracted from the same data with 5M unique customer_id's, how can the value be different.

Is there a way to aggregate and not lose other columns? The other columns have same values for different payment values

Comment: Not exactly sure where your code goes wrong. I did rewrite some parts. `new1<-aggregate(as.numeric(df$payment), list(df$customer_id), mean)`
`inner_join(new1,df,by=c("Group.1"="customer_id"))`. Does this give the same result?

Comment: `names(new1)
[1] "Group.1" "x" ` make sure to rename Group.1 to customer_id.

Comment: Or `new1<-aggregate(df[,'payment'], list(customer_id = df$customer_id), mean)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for such a solution?

This one would just append teh aggregated mean to the original data.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(customer_id) %>%
  mutate(new1 = mean(as.numeric(payment)))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   customer_id [6]
   customer_id payment  new1
   <chr>       <chr>   <dbl>
 1 aks123      109      154.
 2 epfk123     123      273 
 3 jfk1234     342      233 
 4 ekdm453     123      130.
 5 ddd4356     453      453 
 6 epfk123     423      273 
 7 ffg234      1009    1009 
 8 aks123      198      154.
 9 jfk1234     124      233 
10 ekdm453     138      130.
```

Note, your payment column above is a character one. Not sure if that's true for your original data, though.

Another solution is to just keep the unique ids along with the original data (note, the `distinct` function always keeps the first unique ID).

```
df %>%
  group_by(customer_id) %>%
  mutate(new1 = mean(as.numeric(payment))) %>%
  distinct(customer_id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  customer_id payment  new1
  <chr>       <chr>   <dbl>
1 aks123      109      154.
2 epfk123     123      273 
3 jfk1234     342      233 
4 ekdm453     123      130.
5 ddd4356     453      453 
6 ffg234      1009    1009
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
customer_id<-c("aks123","epfk123","jfk1234","ekdm453","ddd4356","epfk123","ffg234","aks123","jfk1234","ekdm453")
payment<-c("109","123","342","123","453","423","1009","198","124","138")
df<-data.frame(customer_id, payment = as.numeric(payment))

new1<-aggregate(df[,'payment'], list(df$customer_id), mean)
names(new1) 
[1] "Group.1" "x"
```

And that way why you were getting the rows doubled because there were no common keys in two data.frames to be merged.

```r
names(new1)[1]  = 'customer_id'
# or pass a named list to aggregate i.e. list(customer_id = df$cumtomer_id)

merge(new1, df)
   customer_id      x payment
1       aks123  153.5     109
2       aks123  153.5     198
3      ddd4356  453.0     453
4      ekdm453  130.5     138
5      ekdm453  130.5     123
6      epfk123  273.0     123
7      epfk123  273.0     423
8       ffg234 1009.0    1009
9      jfk1234  233.0     342
10     jfk1234  233.0     124
```

## extra

You can use the formula version of aggregate when you work with data.frames

```r
aggregate(payment~customer_id, df, mean)
 customer_id payment
1      aks123   153.5
2     ddd4356   453.0
3     ekdm453   130.5
4     epfk123   273.0
5      ffg234  1009.0
6     jfk1234   233.0
```